# prolog input unknown variable in read command

Tags: prolog

I have:

```
byCar(auckland,hamilton).
byCar(hamilton,raglan).

travelSimple2:- write('Travel'),nl,
                write('From where '),read(From),
                write('To where '),read(To),
                write('Using (car/train/plane) '),nl,
                read(Transport),
                travel(From,To,Transport).   

travel(From,To,car):-byCar(From,To).
travel(From,To,car) :- travel(From,Step,car), travel(Step,To,car).
```

First I ask a query:

```
| ?- travel(auckland,raglan,X).
```

Prolog then answer

```
X = car ;
```

but when I ask

```
| ?- travelSimple2.
Travel
From where |: auckland.
To where |: raglan.
Using (car/train/plane) 
|: X.
```

it answered

```
yes
```

so my question is how to make the prolog answer (X=car) like the first query  instead of yes.
Is it possible to do so? I think the command was similar, but why the answer is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think should be

```
travelSimple2:- write('Travel'),nl,
                write('From where '),read(From),
                write('To where '),read(To),
                write('Using (car/train/plane) '),nl,
                travel(From,To,Transport),
                write(Transport),nl.
```

Comment: that way will only always print "car". What I want is user have to input the Transport, if it is an item prolog will answer YES/NO, else if it is an Variable prolog will tell "car". eg: X=car

Comment: @MuAz, CapelliC has the right idea. Just put a `write(Transport), nl` after your `travel` query in the `travelSimple2` predicate. Leave the `read(Transport)` where you have it.